# Windows 8 and memory consumption

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, memory, memory-management

My current system should have enough memory (4GB), but it's the lower average right now and if I want to run multiple applications at once - which is needed - memory is getting scarce.

In addition to make Windows lighter and tablet-friendlier, Microsoft had to reduce the footprint on the HDD of the current iteration, Windows 8. But how does Windows 8 compare to the predecessor in terms of memory consumption? Reviews of Windows 8 often concentrate only on the obvious aspects (look and feel), but not on the improvements from the inside.

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: Are you looking for a detailed article comparing Win8's memory consumption to its predecessors, on all sorts of hardware, with all sorts of drivers/software installed? Why don't you edit your question instead to focus on what *your* actual problem is?

Comment: Lower average, as in on the experience rating? This measures transfer speeds not total capacity.

Comment: With lower average I mean the lower average of typical systems being sold today. You can get systems with 8GB+ on the mainstream market today.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8 consumes less resources than previous versions and is faster than XP even with 1 GB of RAM, as proven by [Troy Hunt](http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/02/operating-system-smackdown-windows-8.html). Vista and Win7 would hardly work with such amount of memory.

But still, 4 GB should be enough for average user. Maybe we could say something more if we know what apps you're using when you're running short on free memory.

Comment: I want to record game video via Open Broadcaster Software, but experienced sporadic stuttering in my previous recordings. I don't know, whether this is because of the CPU (i5 2400s), the HDD or the amount of memory/allocation between game and recording application.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to this article, it explains a possible memory leak:
http://lifehacker.com/5993161/check-runtime-broker-if-youre-running-out-of-ram-on-windows-8

In particular:

> If you find Runtime Broker is using a suspiciously high amount of RAM,
>   try uninstalling any Windows 8 apps you have that utilize live tiles,
>   one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Memory isn't getting scarce, *free* memory is getting scarce. But that's not a problem. Windows will switch memory from one use to another. It does not need to keep memory free in order for it to be available for use.

Free memory is just wasted memory. If you have 1GB free, you might as well have 1GB less memory installed since free memory doesn't actually *do* anything.